# MDTextField mode: 'rectangle' ( hint_text bug )

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

i think i found a bug of MDTextField in mode 'rectagnle'
because on start work correctly but if i save the text of MDTextField in a file.txt and at the next launch of application load the text, the result is this:

[image]

if after i click on MDTextField return to work correctly. But if at the start there is a text, the hint_text is how the image

Comment: Use master branch of KivyMD library - https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD

Comment: @Xyanight i use the master branch, but don't work. i have installed kivymd so: pip3 install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip